# How to make multiple sequence diagrams in single page

Tags: architecture, sequence, diagram, sequence-diagram, plantuml

I wonder if there is any way to make a plantuml two sequence diagram in single page side by side. I want to keep the same actor names in both diagram. Currently if I do something like below, it automatically combined into single sequence diagram.

```
@startuml
Bob -> Alice : hello
@enduml

@startuml
Bob -> Mark : Hi
@enduml
```

[image: sample]

But expected two sequence side by side

Answer (score 26, accepted):

newpage: The newpage keyword is used to split a diagram into several images.

```
@startuml

header SayHello
footer Page %page% of %lastpage%

Bob -> Alice : hello

newpage last page

Bob -> Mark : Hi

@enduml
```

Result:

[image]

[Reference](http://plantuml.com/en/guide)

You also could define a variable like "PAGE_SETTING" to decide whether
on or off it.

```
@startuml

' seton demo
!define PAGE_SETTING newpage

header SayHello
footer Page %page% of %lastpage%

Bob -> Alice : hello

PAGE_SETTING

Bob -> Mark : Hi

@enduml
```

Result:

[image]

[Reference:Macro definition](http://plantuml.com/en/preprocessing)

Comment: Wow thats exactly what I wanted. Thanks Carson Arucard.

Comment: dont know if something has changed, but it is not working anymore..

Comment: Hi @MichałMargiel , This post has been up for a while. You said it suddenly didn't work, so I thought there might be some changes in the new version, and after I updated all the packages ( [plantuml.1.2021.3.jar](https://plantuml.com/en/download) | [Graphviz
2.47.0](https://graphviz.org/download/)  ) and tried again, it still worked. hope you can solve the problem successfully!

Comment: @Carson, maybe its because i am trying onhttp://www.plantuml.com/  and I dont see any way how to display all pages.

Comment: @MichałMargiel it seems that `newpage` does not work, when using the default start/end state `[*]` in state diagrams. There might also be other generated objects, that break `newpage`.

Answer (score 3):

if you just want to mark "newpage" 
you can try something like this

```
@startuml

    ' define
        !define NEW_PAGE_1 == newpage ==

        !definelong NEW_PAGE_2(obj)
            note over obj: newpage
        !enddefinelong

    ' main
        Bob -> Alice : hello
        NEW_PAGE_1
        Bob -> Mark : Hi
        NEW_PAGE_2(Bob)
        Bob -> Carson

@enduml
```

[image]